# Is it safe for my puppy to sleep in my bed?

Tags: dogs, safety, containment, parasites

He is 14 weeks old and was diagnosed with tapeworms four days ago. The doctor prescribed 1/2 tablet for a one time consumption. He is doing well and full of energy. I have been checking his bowels and I don't see any more visible signs but I'm still scared.

Is it safe for my puppy to sleep in my bed even though it had tapeworms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call your Vet and ask how long it will take to clear all of the tapeworms out of his body. Meanwhile, let him sleep on his own bed (or in his crate) until you know he has recovered. Cover his bedding with a sheet, then examine it in the morning and look for signs of the worms... and wash the sheet in hot water.
 [Tapeworms on Pets & Parasites](http://www.petsandparasites.org/dog-owners/tapeworms): now I'm convinced that there's a website for everything.